# Search set of characters inside a string irrespective of its position in PHP

Tags: php, string, search

Hi I would like to get find the set of characters inside a string and then would like to remove it from another string. For eg

```
$start_state = 'BCFSW|';

$possible_combinations = array('BF','BCF','BFS','BFW');
```

I would like the function to search each array element from possible_combinations irrespective of its position. So for eg `'BF'` should `return true` as both the characters are present in `BCFSW|`

I would further want to remove those characters and generate a new array string from it and add it to another array which would look something like this.

```
$possible_states = array ('CSW|BF', 'SW|BCF', 'CW|BFS' ,'CS|BFW')
```

Can you guys please help me with this? It would be of a great help. Thanks

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Can you answer my question?!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `"array_diff" . "array_intersect"`.

Array_diff finds what is not in matching between the arrays, and array_intersect finds what is matching.

```
$str = 'BCFSW|';

$arr = array('BF','BCF','BFS','BFW');

$str = str_split($str);
foreach($arr as $item){
    $temp = str_split($item);
    $new[] = implode("",array_diff($str, $temp)) . implode("",array_intersect($temp, $str));
}

var_dump($new);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "CSW|BF"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "SW|BCF"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "CW|BFS"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "CS|BFW"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/8RvL2

Answer (score -2):

You can use regular expressions with the functions `preg_match` and `preg_replace`

Example with BF:

`$found = preg_match('#B.*F#', $text);`

Will return true if `$text` is BF, BAF, BZZF, ...

You can search all combination in one time if you want by using `|` (see regex documentation for more details)

If order if irrelevant, the regex might be `'#[BF].*[BF]#`

Then, you can use parenthesis to catch characters and change the string with `preg_replace()`